# Android QBCustomObject file uploading The resource wasn't found error

Tags: file-upload, custom-object, quickblox-android

I am trying to upload file using QBCustomObjectFiles ,uploading starts  to show progress in log cat ,but with file field is null and response throws error like this '{"errors":["The resource wasn't found"]}'

I checked My Note Class on Quickblox admin panel,everything seems OK.Also I checked the file (field in method parameter) and it is not null as showing in log cat

```
public void uploadNote(Note note, File file, 
QBEntityCallback<QBCustomObjectFileField> callback, QBProgressCallback 
 progressCallback) {
    QBCustomObject customObject = new QBCustomObject();
    customObject.setClassName(Note.Contract.CLASS_NAME_NOTE);
    customObject.put(Note.Contract.COURSE_ID,note.getCourseId());
    customObject.put(Note.Contract.CATEGORY_ID,note.getCategoryId());
    customObject.put(Note.Contract.DESCRIPTION,note.getDescription());
    customObject.put(Note.Contract.TOPIC,note.getTopic());
    QBCustomObjectsFiles.uploadFile(file, customObject, "noteFile", progressCallback).performAsync(callback);

}
```

This is my log cat :

REQUEST
        POST https://api.quickblox.com/data/Note/null/file.json
    HEADERS
        QuickBlox-REST-API-Version=0.1.1
        QB-SDK=Android 3.9.1
        QB-Token=011a2bc55be67185d4d045d8b2d31
    PARAMETERS
        field_name=noteFile
    INLINE
        POST https://api.quickblox.com/data/Note/null/file.json?field_name=noteFile

and this is response

```
      '{"errors":["The resource wasn't found"]}'
```

The Uploading starts and shows  progress ,but after progress 100 it throws above error.

Answer (score 0):

You should use **QBContent** instead of **QBCustomObjectsFiles**. Example:

```
QBContent.uploadFileTask(file, isPublic, tags, new QBProgressCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressUpdate(int progressValue) {
                //some code for progress
            }
        }).performAsync(new QBEntityCallback<QBFile>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(QBFile qbFile, Bundle params) {
                //some code for success upload
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(QBResponseException responseException) {
                //some code for error upload
            }
        });
```